# spark code to fetch tables from a database

Tags: mysql, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am new to spark and scala.
The thing is I want to fetch the entire data of all the tables in database.
I wrote a code which can fetch for a specific table.

But is it possible that I just pass on my database name and can get the data from all the tables ?

example :

```
val driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
val url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mydb" 
val username = "root"
val password = "*******"


val prop=new Properties()
val conf=new SparkConf().setAppName("Read From SQl").setMaster("local[*]")
val sc=new SparkContext(conf)
val sqlContext=new SQLContext(sc)

prop.setProperty("user", "root")
prop.setProperty("password", "lasitpant")

val df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame =sqlContext.read.jdbc(url, "store_details",prop)

df.createOrReplaceTempView("store_details")
df.schema.printTreeString()
```

The above code fetches for a specific table only.

> Basically I want to extract data say from mysql and then using spark
>   sql do some filtering.. was just wondering rather than creating
>   dataframes for each table by hard coding. is there any other way
>   around

Comment: this seems like un-usal thing. what do you want to do with all table data converted as dataframe? I mean what is the purpose of it ?

Comment: basically i want to extract data say from mysql and then using spark sql do some filtering.. was just wondering rather than creating dataframes for each table by hard coding. is there any other way around

Comment: check my answer hope that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `information_schema.tables` is the way to load the table list as
>   explained in below example program... you can try the below approach..
>   from below code snippet
>
> ```
> val dfTableList = loadTable(url
>       , "information_schema.tables"
>       , user
>       , pass);
> ```

#### Essential Steps

1) First get all table list
2) Map each table to get a dataframe out of it from the below code snippet

```
tableList.map { tableName =>
        val df = loadTable(url
          , schemeName+"."+tableName
          , user
          , pass
          , driverName)

        if (df.isDefined){
          // do what ever you want to do

           df.get.unpersist() //remove form cache
        }
      }
```

***Note : I am using spark 1.6 seems like you are using >1.6 so some syntaxes may vary but approach is same.***

> Final code sample would look like below altogether.. in the below case
>   Im saving in to parquet files. you may ignore that and implement your
>   custom logic...

```
package yourpackage

import org.apache.spark.sql.{SQLContext,DataFrame}

import java.sql.{Connection, Statement, ResultSet}
import java.util.TimeZone
// add other imports like loggers etc....

/**
 * Allows to access to JDBC database scheme and tables and implements methods 
 * to export schemes and tables to Parquet format
 */
object JdbcExporter {

  /** Current SQLContext */
  private var sqlContext: SQLContext = null;

  /** Stored id driver has been loaded */
  private var JDBC_driver_loaded = false;

  /** Name of the JDBC driver */
  private val DefaultJDBC_DriverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

  /** Time zone used to access to JDBC database */
  private val TimeZoneName = java.util.TimeZone.getDefault.getID


  /** Sets the current SQLContext
   * @param _sqlContext Current SQLContext
   */  
  def setSQL_Context(_sqlContext: SQLContext) =
      sqlContext = _sqlContext


  /** Builds a JDBC url to access JDBC databaseto a database using a starting url, user and password.
   *  It fixes the server time zone to 'java.util.TimeZone.getDefault.getID' to avoid
   *  problems when accessing time values
   * @param basicURL Starting url
   * @param user Name of the JDBC database user
   * @param pass Password of the JDBC database user
   * @return A new JDBC url with user and password 
   */      
  private def buildURL(basicURL: String
    , user: String
    , pass: String): String = {

    s"$basicURL?user=$user&password=$pass&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=$TimeZoneName"
  }


  /** Loads a JDBC driver
   * @param driverName Name of the driver
   * @return true if has been properly loaded
              or false if cluster has not been properly loaded 
   */  
  def loadDriver(driverName: String) : Boolean = {

    logInfo(s"Loading JDBC driver '$driverName'")

    try{
      Class.forName(driverName).newInstance
      logInfo(s"JDBC driver '$driverName' loaded sucessfully")
      JDBC_driver_loaded = true;
      true
    }
    catch{
      case e: Exception  => {
        logError(e,s"Error loading JDBC driver '$driverName'. ")
        JDBC_driver_loaded = false;
        false
      }
    }
  }


  /** Gets a table from a JDBC database and create a dataframe with it content
   * @param url JDBC url
   * @param tableName Name of the JDBC database table
   * @param user Name of the JDBC database user
   * @param pass Password of the JDBC database user
   * @param driverName Name of the JDBC driver
   * @return true if dataframe has been properly created
             or false if dataframe has not been properly created 
   */
  def loadTable(url: String
    , tableName: String
    , user: String
    , pass: String
    , driverName: String = DefaultJDBC_DriverName) : Option[DataFrame] = {

    logInfo(s"Loading table '$tableName' from '$url'")

    //check if driver is loaded
    if (!JDBC_driver_loaded){
      if (!loadDriver(driverName))
        return None
    }

    var df : DataFrame = null
    try {
      val prop = new java.util.Properties
      prop.setProperty("driver", driverName)

      df = sqlContext.read.jdbc(buildURL(url,user,pass)
        , tableName
        , prop) //connectionProperties

      Some(df)
    }
    catch {
        case e: Exception => logError(e, s"Error loading table from ' $url'")
        None
      }
  }


  /** Gets the name list of the JDBC database tables stored in a JDBC scheme 
   * @param url JDBC url
   * @param tableName Name of the JDBC database table
   * @param user Name of the JDBC database user
   * @param pass Password of the JDBC database user
   * @param driverName Name of the JDBC driver
   * @return Name list of the tables of the scheme
             or None if case of error or empty scheme 
   */
  def getTableListFromScheme(url: String
    , schemeName: String
    , user: String
    , pass: String
    , driverName: String = DefaultJDBC_DriverName): Option[Array[String]] = {

    val dfTableList = loadTable(url
      , "information_schema.tables"
      , user
      , pass);

    if (!dfTableList.isDefined) return None

    val df = dfTableList.get
    val temporalTable = "tableNameList"
    val query = s"select table_name from $temporalTable where table_schema='$schemeName'"
    df.registerTempTable(temporalTable)         //associate a temporal table to the loaded table
    var dfSQL = df.sqlContext.sql(query)        //execute query on temporal table
    scala.util.Try(sqlContext.dropTempTable(temporalTable)) //delete temporal table
    Some(dfSQL.rdd.map(r => r(0).asInstanceOf[String]).collect)  //get the result
  }


  /** Saves a JDBC database table into Parquet format, deleting previous content in the output 
   * @param schemeName Name of the scheme of the table 
   * @param tableName Name of the table
   * @param df Data of the table
   * @param rootPath Path to store the formatted data
   */
  def saveFileAsParquet(schemeName: String
    , tableName: String
    , df: DataFrame
    , rootPath: String) {
/// ExportUtil is custom class for interacting with hdfs and files you can implement your own stuff 
//DFUtil is another helper class you can implement reusable methods here
      val path = ExportUtil.ensureEndWithFileSeparator(rootPath)+tableName
      ExportUtil.deleteDirectory(path)
      ExportUtil.ensureDirectoryExist(path)

      DFUtil.saveDataframeAsParquet(sqlContext
        , df
        , path)
  }


  /** Saves a complete JDBC database scheme into Parquet format
   * @param url JDBC url
   * @param schemeName Name of the scheme 
   * @param user Name of the JDBC database user
   * @param pass Password of the JDBC database user 
   * @param rootPath Path to store the formatted data
   * @param driverName Name of the JDBC driver
   */
  def saveSchemeAsParquet(url: String
    , schemeName: String
    , user: String
    , pass: String
    , rootPath: String
    , driverName: String = DefaultJDBC_DriverName) : Boolean = {

    logInfo(s"Converting into Parquet format scheme: '$schemeName' into root path: '$rootPath'")

    val tableList = getTableListFromScheme(url
      , schemeName
      , user
      , pass
      , driverName)

     if (!tableList.isDefined) return false

    saveTableListAsParquet(url
      , schemeName
      , tableList.get
      , user
      , pass
      , rootPath
      , driverName)

    logInfo(s"Converted into Parquet format scheme: '$schemeName' into root path: '$rootPath'")
  }


  /** Saves a JDBC database table name list into Parquet format
   * @param url JDBC url 
   * @param schemeName Name of the scheme 
   * @param tableList Table name list
   * @param user Name of the JDBC database user
   * @param pass Password of the JDBC database user 
   * @param rootPath Path to store the formatted data
   * @param driverName Name of the JDBC driver
   */
  def saveTableListAsParquet(url: String
    , schemeName: String
    , tableList: Seq[String]
    , user: String
    , pass: String
    , rootPath: String
    , driverName: String = DefaultJDBC_DriverName) : Boolean = {

     val tableListAsString = tableList.mkString(",")
     val count = tableList.size
     logInfo(s"Converting into Parquet a list of $count tables: $tableListAsString into root path: '$rootPath'")

     tableList.map { tableName =>
        val df = loadTable(url
          , schemeName+"."+tableName
          , user
          , pass
          , driverName)

        if (df.isDefined){
          saveFileAsParquet(schemeName
           , tableName
           , df.get
           , ExportUtil.ensureEndWithFileSeparator(rootPath)+schemeName)

           df.get.unpersist() //remove form cache
        }
      }
      logInfo(s"Converted into Parquet a list of $count tables: $tableListAsString into root path: '$rootPath'")
  } 
}
```